# Is there better way to reference as hash?

Tags: perl

If I have deep multi-level (dynamic) hash-structure, I try to reference deeper parts through separate variables, something like this:

```
my $multilevel_dynamic_hash;
my $dynamic_a = int( rand() * 100 );
my $dynamic_b = int( rand() * 100 );
my $dynamic_c = int( rand() * 100 );

$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = {};
my $reference_as_hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c };

call_to_some_subroutine( $reference_as_hashref );
```

Now, instead of those two lines

```
$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = {};
my $reference_as_hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c };
```

is there possible to avoid the first line and declare `$reference_as_hashref` so that it treats the last part (`$dynamic_c`) as key to the next level of hash?

**EDIT**

I'd like to take reference, something like this:

```
my $reference_as_hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c }{};
```

NB! last `{}`

Instead, first I have to tell that the value is hashref and then I can reference it. Is it possible with one step?

Comment: What do you mean? `$dynamic_c` is used as a key

Comment: @ikegami Of course, made correction

Comment: Adding a grammar error doesn't help :( And it still asks how to treat `$dyanmic_c` as a key (which you're already doing).

Comment: Are you searching for [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver)?

Comment: @choroba I want to make temporary meaningful references for deep data structures for better operability. I make them with 2 lines. For curiosity I wanted to know, is it possible to make them in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to reduce code duplication, you could simply change the order in you which you assign things.

For example,

```
$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = {};
my $hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c };
```

and

```
my $hashref = {};
$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = $hashref;
```

produce the same result.

However, there is an even simpler solution.

```
$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = {};
my $hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c };
```

can also be written as

```
my $hashref = $multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = {};
```

Scalar assignment is right-associative, so `$a = $b = $c;` is equivalent to `$a = ( $b = $c );`. It returns its left-hand side, so `$a = ( $b = $c )` is equivalent to `$b = $c; $a = $b;`

Comment: Delete the irrelevant part. Added an explanation. Added an alternative solution (the first one).

Comment: This is the syntax I was looking for, thank you! Sorry for the poor selection of words. The alternative solution is pretty mind blowing, but logical.

Comment: Hash elements are just scalars, and references (such as the one returned by `{ }`) are just scalar values.

Comment: By the way, that means you could also do  `$multilevel_dynamic_hash->{ $dynamic_a }{ $dynamic_b }{ $dynamic_c } = my $hashref = {};` :)

Comment: Keep coming! ;)